# How to insert structure object to set in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

I am trying to add some items to set and map but insert to the map and set giving an error

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include<set>
#include<map>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    long number;
    std::string name;
    double amount;
    long volume;
} person_struct;

person_struct _struct;
set<person_struct> myset;
map < string, set<person_struct>> mymap;

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    _struct.number = 100;
    _struct.name = "TOM";
    _struct.amount = 111;
    _struct.volume = 230;

   myset.insert(_struct);
   mymap.insert(_struct.name, myset);

       return 0;
}
```

Error:

> Error 1   error C2664:
>   'std::_Tree_const_iterator>>
>   std::set,std::allocator<_Kty>>::insert(std::_Tree_const_iterator>>,const
>   person_struct &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'person_struct *'
>   to 'person_struct &&'

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: And the error actually is what? Post a [MCVE] please, as usual and required.

Comment: Also, you declared `myset` twice.

Comment: `set<TYPE>` requires that `TYPE` has a comparison function so it can tell if the same element is already in the set.

Comment: You need to define a function `less<person_struct>`

Comment: that's impossible.  It says you are passing a pointer to insert but _struct isn't a pointer.  Are you sure that is the error for the code that is posted?

Comment: The error message looks like your real code is `myset.insert(&_struct);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) is an ordered set of unique elements, so you have to define `operator <` for your struct.

On the other hand, you could use `std::unordered_set` - then you'd have to specialize `std::hash` functor for your struct (or provide some other hasher as `unordered_set` template argument).

Comment: thanks Lgor, how to add structure to map?

Comment: your_map.insert(std::make_pair(key, value)); Or: your_map[key] = value;

Comment: Thank you very much